# Convert Windows CryptoAPI PRIVATE KEY BLOB to bouncy castle RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, cryptoapi

Is there any way (similar to FromCapiPrivateKeyBlob in Mono) to convert a Windows CryptoAPI PRIVATE KEY BLOB to RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters used by Bouncy Castle?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities class to see what is there in the way of conversions.

I will look at adding methods for interop with CryptoAPI blobs.